# create ActiveMQ MQTT broker to connect to Moquitto broker

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, mqtt

I want to use ActiveMQ to create a broker to connect to another Mosquitto broker.
And then, I can use ActiveMQ to receive the message from Mosquitto broker.

What I am done now is:

1. integrate the ActiveMQ with JBoss EAP 6.3.
2. create MQTT broker in ActiveMQ: http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html

But after I add NetworkConnector in broker-config.xml:

```
<transportConnectors>
  <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
  <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://localhost:1883"/>
</transportConnectors>

<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://mosquitto_server_ip:1883)"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

the server shows exception after starting:

> "Network connection between vm://localhost#8 and
>   tcp:///mosquitto_server_ip:1883@42688 shutdown due to a remote error:
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException"

I also try to use "mqtt://..." to connect, but it's still failed:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters:
>   {wireFormat.host=0.0.0.0}

Does anyone know how to use JBoss ActiveMQ to connect to mosquitto broker?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, the ActiveMQ Network Connector only works between ActiveMQ brokers using the native OpenWire protocol, MQTT is not supported.  You would need to use something like Camel or some other bridging mechanism to support cross broker communication between ActiveMQ and Mosquito